# How to properly create an array of arrays by reading in data from a file

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

So far I have:

```
//read in data from CSV file and separate it into 'row' strings:
// where dataString is simply a CSV file with lines of CSV data
// 31 lines with 9 integers in each line
NSArray *containerArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
NSArray *rowTemp; //local variable just for my sake
NSMutableArray *tableArray;//mutable array to hold the row arrays

//For each index of containerArray:
//take the string object (string of CSV data) and then,
//create an array of strings to be added into the final tableArray

    for (int i = 0; i < [containerArray count]; i++) {
    rowTemp = [[containerArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    [tableArray addObject:rowTemp];        
    }
```

Then when I try the following, it returns: (null)

```
NSLog(@"Row 6, cell 1 is %@", [[tableArray objectAtIndex:5] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Any ideas? is there a better way?

FYI this data is static and very unlikely to change. Any way to create and populate a static array rather than using a mutable array, would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just got the answer! with some help from iPhoneSDK forums, and what I failed to do was actually create the tableArray. What I did in the code above was merely create the variable.
  
    NSMutableArray *tableArray;

and did not actually create the mutable array I wanted. Instead what I should have done was:

    NSMutableArray *tableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [containerArray count]];

Which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer! with some help from iPhoneSDK forums, and what I failed to do was actually create the tableArray. What I did in the code above was merely create the variable. NSMutableArray *tableArray; and did not actually create the mutable array I wanted. Instead what I should have done was: NSMutableArray *tableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [containerArray count]]; Which worked like a charm.